# Proper notation to denote "take the derivative of this"

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was working on a related rates calculus problem on my math homework. The point of the problem is to start with the area formula of a triangle, $A= \frac 12 b\dot{}h$ and then to take the derivative. Since base, height, and area are all changing variables in this word problem, I treated A, b and h as variables, not constants and took the derivative of all three and used the product rule for the right side of the equation.

$$dA = \frac 12 (b \ dh + h \ db)$$

I know how to *take* the derivative, but not how to mathematically write "take the derivative of this function". I know that $y'$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ *is* the derivative of the function and if I had the equation $y = x^2$
then I would write $[\frac{d}{dx}] y =[ \frac{d}{dx} ]x^2$ to say "take the derivative of the function". But what if I have additional variables, how would you write "take the derivative" in math terms? And how would all of the dx's dy's, etc. cancel out?

Comment: You take the derivative with respect to a certain variable. Then write $$\frac{d}{dx}$$ if the variable is $x$

Comment: If you are taking the derivative with respect to $b$ then you have to calculate $dA/db$ and $dh/db$

Comment: Strictly speaking, "all of the dx's, dy's, etc." do **not** "cancel out".  $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is **not** a fraction, and the "dx" and "dy" are **not** separate terms.   However, the derivative **is** the *limit* of a fraction so we can go back "before" the limit, use the fraction property, then take the limit to show that the "fraction property" works for the derivative.

Comment: @Math_QED: Or, by "derivative" you mean take the differential, in which case it doesn't need to be with respect to a variable at all.

Comment: Yeah, but then the OP should have mentioned another term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're saying that $A,b,h$ are all changing with respect to some other variable (let's call it $t$ for time), in which case I'd say you took the derivative with respect to $t$ of both sides, writing $\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{2}bh\right] = \frac{1}{2}\left(b\frac{dh}{dt} + h\frac{db}{dt}\right)$. The equation you wrote seems to re-express this using infinitesimals to "cancel the $dt$'s".

Comment: @Ryan assuming Gregory is correct and you are taking the derivative WRT to another variable, $t$ for instance, you are on firmer ground if you don't "cancel the $dt$'s". Notationally, it is a little more verbose, but you could always say $A^\prime = \frac12(bh^\prime+hb^\prime)$ if you want to have more compact notation.

Answer (score 0):

The more useful concept here is the *differential*. $\mathrm{d}A$ is the differential of $A$ (it is not unreasonable to call it the "derivative" of $A$)

Differentials satisfy all of the algebraic properties you expect derivatives to have. Also, if $f$ is a differentiable univariate function, then $\mathrm{d}f(z) = f'(z) \mathrm{d}z$, no matter what $z$ is.

In your case, you have correctly computed the differential of $A$: you do indeed have

$$ \mathrm{d}A = \frac 12 (b \ \mathrm{d}h + h \ \mathrm{d}b) $$

Depending on the problem, one might continue on to do things like:

- Set one of the differentials to zero, because that variable is being held constant
- Do additional computations on $\mathrm{d}h$ and $\mathrm{d}b$. For example, you may have $h$ written as a function of $b$, or both as functions of some third variable $t$
- Solve for one of the other differentials
- If you arrive at a formula that expresses one differential as a multiple of another differential, then taking the ratio gives the usual derivative (i.e. as you learned in introductory calculus) that the notation suggests.